# how to get buttonId was pressed in android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the following piece of code:

```
OnClickListener button_listener = new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 ImageButton ibutton = (ImageButton) v; 
                 if(player == 0)
                 {

                     ibutton.setClickable(false);
                     ibutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.crossnew);
                     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     player = 1;
                 }

                 else if(player == 1)
                 {
                     ibutton.setClickable(false);
                     ibutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.zeronew);
                     player = 0;
                 }
            }

        };
```

how to get buttonId was pressed;
help me please

Comment: v.getId() in onClick() method.

Comment: when Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); was active, it become false

Comment: Toast.makeText() is overloaded:

1) makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)

2) makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)

you accidentally used version 1), which takes a resource id as second parameter (and there is no String with the given id)
please check my updated answer

and for reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OnClickListener button_listener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(v.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Well done sir! Was halfway through typing that out when I saw your answer :P

Comment: updated the answer, @Pandia Vinra made a mistake with Toast.makeText(), v.getId() works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
if(v.getid() == R.id.testButton){
   Log.e("--->","click on testButton");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your on click use a switch case.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getid()) // get id 
{
    case R.id.button1 :
         // button 1 clicked
      break;
    case R.id.button2 :
          // button 2 clicked
      break;   
} 
}
```

Edit:

In your comment displaying toast you are using application context.

Use a activity context in place of application context. Check the answer by commonsware

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/)

Answer (score 0):

In Button click function just use

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                        int id = v.getId();
           }
```

this will serve your purpose.